# VSphere statistics interpretation

Tags: vmware-esxi, vsphere-client

Is there a simple summary...couple pages, maybe...explaining statistics and management information for VM's using vSphere Client 4 so we know about tuning VM's? Things like what's good or bad for host CPU, host mem, guest mem, performance counters to watch...I know what these *probably* are or should be, but I'd rather see a decent reference to verify things than assume I know it and be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a succinct summary for vSphere yet but there are quite a few presentations archived on VMworld.com that provide very good information on interpreting performance statistics and tuning with VI3. Most of this information is directly applicable to VI4\vSphere. You will have to register to watch\read the archives but it is well worth it.
For VI3 there is a pretty good session called "Interpreting Performance Statistics in VI3" from September last year - it is a recorded presentation but don't let that put you off in any way it's a great explanation of how to use the VI Client and ESXTOP to monitor what's actually happening with your hosts (and clusters).

It's not a short summary though unfortunately but in my view very much worth looking at.

With any luck there will be something similar for VI4 at the upcoming VMWorld that will cover the enhancements to monitoring and performance overview capabilities in vSphere.

Comment: Here is the URL at VMworld.com for the "Interpreting Performance Statistics in VI3" session - http://www.vmworld.com/docs/DOC-2148

Answer (score 1):

Scott Drummond's [Pivot Point](http://vpivot.com/) blog has some good information on VMware ESX/VSphere performance including this post [Performance Troubleshooting: No PhD Required!](http://vpivot.com/2009/09/18/performance-troubleshooting-no-phd-required/) which has links to more information on the performance counters of vCenter, esxtop and vscsiStats.

Here are some links on CPU Ready times as well which can be critical to CPU performance problems:

- [What is CPU READY?](http://vmfaq.com/entry/42/)
- [Understanding Ready Time](http://viops.vmware.com/home/docs/DOC-1404.pdf)
- [VMware ESX Server 3- Ready Time Observations](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/esx3_ready_time.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is a breakout session scheduled for VMworld 2009 titled "esxtop for advanced users"

Comment: I think esxtop is run on the ESX host, but ESXi doesn't have the traditional console interface unless you use the "unsupported" console to enable SSHD and tools first, does it?

Comment: You can install the RCLI (on a Linux or Windows machine) and use the resxtop to get the info from ESXi servers.